# Possible to make a phone call from WP7 application?

Tags: .net, windows-phone-7

as stated above is it possible to make a phone call from within inside a wp7 app? If not is it possible to launch the "Phone Application" similar to the SMSTask class or EmailTask class from within our applications?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to start a PhoneCallTask

[Details here](http://www.nickharris.net/2010/09/how-to-place-a-phone-call-on-windows-phone-7-using-phonecalltask/)

Comment: Is anyway to make a phone call without use PhoneCallTask.Show()? I want to build an Dialer for WP7 and I don't want to click Call on my app and click Call in Phone Application agian!